# Properties of Feynman diagrams in Fermi's effective interaction theory

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, interactions

What are the properties of the Feynman diagrams in Fermi's effective interaction theory and how can one draw a Feynman diagram in this theory in relation to the Feynman diagram in the standard model and the reaction equation?

Comment: This is, at present, a really broad question. Can you be more specific on what you're looking for in terms of "properties"? Also, in general there's not a one-to-one correspondence between Feynman diagrams and reaction equations, with there always being an infinite number of Feynman diagrams for every reaction equation.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform matching (to find an effective action) in reverse? That is, the diagrams in the full theory that a lower order effective diagram consists of?

Comment: Are you asking 'what feynman rules has the fermi's theory? How can I make a prediction on base of it? Why it's not renormalizable?'